# retrieve data and show in my webpage by seperating view and model

Tags: php, html

This is my second question on php. I'm trying to query mysql database and show it on my page.

Currently, I'm doing it on php page and the code is as below.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbUserName = "myUserId";
$dbPassword = "MyPwd";
$dbname = "MyDBName";
try
{
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbname);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo 'Error : ' . $ex->getMessage();
}

$SELECT = "SELECT * FROM OpenPositions";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $SELECT);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
      
       <div class="welcome-two">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="welcome-detail">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col">
                            <h2>Open <b>one</b></h2>
                            <div class="tabs">
                                <?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ ?>
     <div class="tab">
                                    <input type="radio" id="rd<?php echo $row['JobId']; ?>" name="rd">
                                    <label class="tab-label" for="rd<?php echo $row['JobId']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></label>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                    <?php echo $row['JobDescription']; ?><br/>
                                                                        <p><button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
     <?php
} ?>
                                
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <script>
        var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItem');
        var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItemHeading');
        for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
            accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
        }
        function toggleItem() {
            var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;
            for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
                accItem[i].className = 'accordionItem close';
            }
            if (itemClass == 'accordionItem close') {
                this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem open';
            }
        }
        // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Using this, I'm able to retrieve my data and display it. But, This is working when I save it as php.

Here I've 2 questions.

1. How can I separate the code and have HTML displaying data and php doing db related tasks?
2. When I click on the button, how can I pass the id and show it in the modal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't really separate all of the php and HTML thing. But you can do something like this:

first create 2 file:

1. db_connection_function.php
2. index.php // Yeah, you can't escape from .php file extension.

relocate your database connection and query to file `db_connection_function.php`

```php
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbUserName = "myUserId";
$dbPassword = "MyPwd";
$dbname = "MyDBName";
try
{
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbname);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo 'Error : ' . $ex->getMessage();
}

$SELECT = "SELECT * FROM OpenPositions";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $SELECT);

?>
```

And this content of file `index.php`

```html
<?php include 'db_connection_function.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
      
       <div class="welcome-two">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="welcome-detail">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col">
                            <h2>Open <b>one</b></h2>
                            <div class="tabs">
                                <?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ ?>
     <div class="tab">
                                    <input type="radio" id="rd<?php echo $row['JobId']; ?>" name="rd">
                                    <label class="tab-label" for="rd<?php echo $row['JobId']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></label>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                    <?php echo $row['JobDescription']; ?><br/>
                                                                        <p><button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
     <?php
} ?>
                                
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <script>
        var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItem');
        var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItemHeading');
        for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
            accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
        }
        function toggleItem() {
            var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;
            for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
                accItem[i].className = 'accordionItem close';
            }
            if (itemClass == 'accordionItem close') {
                this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem open';
            }
        }
        // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

About how to pass id to your modal is like this:

first, put your data 'id' in the attribute of modal button

```html
...
<p><button class="myBtn" data-id="<?php echo $row['JobId']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
...
```

must change "myBtn" to class, because id can't be used to many data.

And this is for your modal

```js
$(".myBtn").click(function(){
  JobId = $(this).data('id')
  // put the id into modal
  $('div#myModal div.modal-content p').html(JobId)
})
```